# Ricci flow and conformal classes

Tags: conformal-geometry, ricci-flow

Is it true that the conformal class of the metric is preserved under Ricci flow? I have seen it mentioned in an answer on this site. Is there an easy argument?

(This question was asked on MSE but it has not received any answer there.)

Answer (score 8):

It's true in dimension $2$ but not in higher dimensions, at least not in general.

Comment: In fact, if the conformal class is preserved we have $g(t) = \lambda(t,x) g_0$ for some function $t$, which by the Ricci flow forces the Ricci curvature to be proportional to the metric. Using that the Einstein tensor is divergence free for any Riemannian manifold, in dimension $n > 2$ this implies that $\lambda(t,x) = \lambda(t)$ and so your solution at each time $t$ is an Einstein manifold.